# Como voltar para o modal anterior no Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-3

Estou em um modal, quero clicar em um botão e voltar para o modal anterior no Bootstrap + Javascript.

Comment: poste seu codigo

Comment: Adicione o código do modal e da página que chama ele.

Answer (score 1):

Conseguir resolver o problema com o seguinte código :

```
$('#modalVisualizarTamanho').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
$('#modalVisualizarComponentes').modal('show');    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

tente usar:

```
$('#modalItensRomaneio').modal('toggle');
```